# Многопоточность на Nodejs 12

Tags: node.js

Необходимо отправить миллионы Push уведомлений в сутки.
Хотелось бы выйти 1000 сообщений в секунду. На данный момент не удается преодолеть предел в 100 в секунду. Возможно проблема в оптимизации кода.

```
Сервер Centos7
20 ядер
256гб оперативка
PostgresSQL 9.6
```

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push
Также подключен модуль worker_threads

Скажите с такими конфигурациями реально достичь такого результата?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что без примера того, как вы эти пуши отправляете, помочь вам никто не сможет?